# How to differentiate this integral with variable limits?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, statistics

Source of the question: the exercise 2.18 of Statistical Inference Book by Casella and Berger.

Show that if X is a continuous random variable, then

$$\min_a E|X-a|=E|X-m|$$, where m is the median.

My attempt:

$$E|X-a|=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x-a|f(x)dx=  \int_{-\infty}^a -(x-a)f(x)dx + \int_a^\infty (x-a)f(x)dx$$. Then

$$\frac{d}{da} E|X-a|=$$

I don't know how to do this differentiation. I need to set it to zero.

By using herb steinberg's hint,

$$E|X-a|=-\int_{-\infty}^a xf(x)dx + a \int_{-\infty}^af(x)dx+\int_a^\infty xf(x)dx-a\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$$

Then by using Henry's hint,

$$\frac{d}{da} E|X-a|= -af(a)+af(a)-af(a)+af(a)$$. But this is always zero. Somewhere must go wrong.

Comment: With well-behaved functions you have $\frac{d}{da} \int^a_{-\infty} g(x)\, dx = g(a)$ and $\frac{d}{da} \int_a^{+\infty} g(x)\, dx = -g(a)$.  Well-behaved includes $g(x)$ being continuous and the integrals being finite

Comment: @Henry I still cannot get the answer.

Comment: You can split each integral into two, with integrands xf(x) and f(x), where the second has a outside the integration.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I edit something new. Still need help

Comment: Let $F(a) = \int_{-\infty}^a f(x) \mathrm d x$. You want to differentiate $a \int_{-\infty}^a f(x) \mathrm d x = a F(a)$ then you should apply product rule.
$(aF(a))^\prime = F(a) + a\cdot F^\prime(a) = F(a) + af(a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derivatives are wrong.  $\frac{d}{da}(a\int\limits_{-\infty}^a f(x)dx)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^a f(x)dx+af(a)$  and $\frac{d}{da}(a\int\limits_a^\infty f(x)dx)=\int\limits_a^\infty f(x)dx-af(a)$.  Putting it all together  $\frac{d}{da}E|X-a|=\int\limits_{-\infty}^a f(x)dx-\int\limits_a^\infty f(x)dx$.  When $a=m$, $\frac{d}{da}E|X-a|=0$.